# Hot to get int value of generic Java Enum in Scala

Tags: java, scala, enums

I have some Enums declared in java file:

```
public class Enums {    
public static enum Achievement {NORMAL, PROGRESSIVE}
public static enum Log {INFO,WARNING,ERROR}
public static enum Game {ONE_TIME, GRADUAL}}
```

Now in scala file let's assume i have:

```
val key: Log = Log.INFO
val typ: Class[_] = getType(key)
```

What I need is to do:

```
Enum.valueOf(typ, "INFO")
```

Unfortunatelly this approach leads to miscelanious type errors like

```
 > Error:(65, 29) type mismatch;
 found   : Class[?0] where type ?0
 required: Class[T]
      val nr = Enum.valueOf(result,
                            ^
```

Do you have any ideas? Is there any way to create an enum or get its ordinal in this situation? getType uses reflection to find field's type in class and pattern match it to convert it.

EDIT<<<<<<

Solved it by simply:

```
  val enum  = typ.getEnumConstants().find(_.toString.equals("INFO"))
  val ordinal = enum match {
    case Some(enum) => enum.asInstanceOf[Enum[_]].ordinal()
    case None =>
  }
```

Comment: You can't get an ordinal from typ as its the class. Or should typ really one of the values of the enum?

Comment: Can't you just do: `val e = Enums.Log.valueOf("INFO")`?

Comment: No, because all I have is 'typ' and I know only that it is class of Java enum. It could be Achievement, Log or Game and exception after passing "INFO" to valueOf is fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

Class's type parameter is always a hiccup.

```
scala> def typ[A <: Enum[A]]: Class[A] = classOf[Thread.State].asInstanceOf[Class[A]]
typ: [A <: Enum[A]]=> Class[A]

scala> Enum.valueOf[Thread.State](typ, "RUNNABLE")
res7: Thread.State = RUNNABLE

scala> Enum.valueOf(typ[Thread.State], "RUNNABLE")
res8: Thread.State = RUNNABLE
```

Comment: It was close but unfortunatelly I couldn't pass expression like Thread.State to classOf operator. Solved it another way. Thanks.

Comment: I was in a rush earlier and meant to comment -- you could pass a ClassTag to typ -- but your solution is also nice. I used to use java enums often, but no longer, so it's helpful to refresh.